# Vue Router routes not tracked by Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-router, firebase-analytics

I'd like to know if there's some configuration I might've missed when setting up Firebase Analytics for a Vue app (and for SPAs in general, I suppose) to get it to track page changes, because when I'm in Firebase's DebugView, it doesn't track `page_view`s unless I refresh the page or manually enter a URL into the browser. I know for the regular Google Analytics module (`vue-analytics`) you have to pass it the router object on initialisation for it to work ([more about that](https://webdeasy.de/en/how-to-integrate-google-analytics-on-your-vue-js-page/)) so it makes sense to me that you'd have to do something similar with Firebase Analytics, but I can't find anything in the docs about it.

I've tried manually calling `logEvent('page_view')` from my `router.afterEach()` guard, but then it logs each page change multiple times.

Please let me know if there's any info or demo code you'd like me to include.

Answer (score 2):

So this doesn't fix the problem, per se, but it's what I'm going with until a better answer comes along.

Moving the `logEvent('page_view')` from the `router.afterEach()` guard to the `router.beforeEach()` guard prevents it from being logged multiple times in Firebase Analytics, and adding a custom `type` parameter allows me to distinguish between an actual page change/load and an internal "SPA" page change/load. So (the relevant part of) my router code now looks like this:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  firebase.analytics().logEvent('page_view', { type: 'internal' });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Tracking *page_view* in single page applications can be tricky with Google Analytics

You can go to your Google Analytics Dashboard and turn on **Enhanced measurement**

Admin > Data Streams > Select your Data Stream > Activate **Enhanced measurement**

You can read more here: [Track Single Page App with Google Analytics 4](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/?utm_medium=video&utm_source=youtube.com&utm_campaign=am%20yt%20-%20single%20page%20applications%202021)